# How to prove that if $(ab,n)=1$ then, $(r,n)=1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, euclidean-algorithm

Let $ab=nq+r$ where all variables represent integers with $0\leq r<n$. If $(ab,n)=1$ then how to prove that $(r,n)=1$? I need to prove this to help me understand the proof of Euler's theorem better.

I have been able to reason it out verbally but I want to prove it rigorously using equations. If $d=(r,n)$ then $d|r$ and $d|n$. Therefore $d|(nq+r)$. Therefore $d|ab$. But $(ab,n)=1$. Since $d|n$ and $d|ab$, hence $d=1$. Therefore $(r,n)=1$. I cannot figure out how to frame the equations to express this. Please help.

Comment: What you have written , starting from "If $d = (r,n)$" and ending with "Therefore $(r,n) = 1$" is an *acceptable rigorous mathematical proof*! You have figured out how to frame the equations, and the explanation is also correct. Once again I repeat, your argument is fine. "Reasoning it out verbally" would be something like : "Any divisor of $r$ and $n$ is by the given equation a divisor of $ab$ and $n$ and hence a divisor of $1$, hence equal to $1$".

Comment: Hint: use [Bezout's lemma] (https://proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma)

Comment: $1 = (ab,n) = (nq+r,n) = (r,n)\,$ by the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

By Bezout $$uab+vn=1$$ for somme $u,v\in \mathbb Z$. Then $$unq+ru+nv=1\implies ru+n(uq+v)=1\implies (r,n)=1.$$